# Return value from function with alternate entry

Tags: fortran

When a function has an alternate entry, is it necessary to set the return value for the entry name, or will the primary name always work if the alternate name is not set? For example,

```
      INTEGER FUNCTION MYFUNC( ARG )
        INTEGER ARG
        INTEGER MYFUNC2
C         ... do something here...
        GOTO 100
        ENTRY MYFUNC2( ARG )
C         ... do something else here
  100   CONTINUE
        MYFUNC = <some value>
C         .. is the next line needed, of can it be omitted?
        myfunc2 = myfunc
        RETURN
        END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing the Fortran 2008 Standard, Cl. 12.6.2.6 *ENTRY statement*:

> [...]
>
> 3 If the ENTRY statement is in a function subprogram, an additional
>   function is defined by that subprogram. The name of the function is
>   entry-name and the name of its result variable is result-name or is
>   entry-name if no result-name is provided. 
>   [...]
>   **If the characteristics of the result of the
>   function named in the ENTRY statement are the same as the
>   characteristics of the result of the function named in the FUNCTION
>   statement, their result variables identify the same variable, although
>   their names need not be the same.** Otherwise, they are storage
>   associated and shall all be nonpointer, nonallocatable scalars that
>   are default integer, default real, double precision real, default
>   complex, or default logical.

The way I read the highlighted passage is that the line

```
myfunc2 = myfunc
```

is indeed not required since `MYFUNC` and `MYFUNC2` are both scalar integers of the same kind.

---

Since no `result` is specified with either the function statement nor the entry statement, the function name becomes *result-name*. This is specified in Cl. 12.6.2.2 *Function subprogram*

> [...]
>
> 4 If RESULT appears, the name of the result variable of the function
>   is result-name and all occurrences of the function name in
>   execution-part statements in its scope refer to the function itself.
>   **If RESULT does not appear, the name of the result variable is
>   function-name** and all occurrences of the function name in
>   execution-part statements in its scope are references to the result
>   variable. [...]

Comment: About the only thing missing from this answer is: "don't use the `entry` statement".